# Django EmailMultiAlternatives not attaching pdf

Tags: python, django, email, pdf

I have the following code in Python to send an email with an attached pdf.

```
result_url = '%s%s?analysis_id=%s' % (
        constants.HOST_URL, reverse('results'), analysis.id)
pdf_filename = ''.join(['report', str(analysis_id), '.pdf'])
utils.convert_to_pdf(result_url, pdf_filename)
```

and here is my `utils.convert_to_pdf`.

```
def convert_to_pdf(url, filename):
    command = "phantomjs export.js %s %s" % (url, filename)
    execute_command(command).communicate()
```

and here is how I am sending the email.

```
email_ids = []
if analysis.user is not None:
    email_ids.append(analysis.user.email)

if email is not None:
    email_ids.append(email)

body = ANALYSIS_EMAIL_BODY % (result_url)

try:
    message = EmailMultiAlternatives(ANALYSIS_EMAIL_SUBJECT, body, settings.EMAIL_SENDER, email_ids)
    message.attach('Report.pdf', pdf_filename, 'application/pdf')
    message.send() 
except Exception as ex:
    logging.error('Send mail failed: %s', ex)
```

Now I see the PDF file is properly getting generated in my current folder and is attached with the mail but it's size is 0KB in the mail and when I try to open the file it tells .

`It may be damaged or use a file format that preview doesn't recognize`

What is going wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You are merely attaching the filename as the contents of the file.

You need to attach the actual contents, not a filename.

```
message.attach('Report.pdf', read_pdf_contents(), 'application/pdf')
```

It is your job to determine how to get the raw data from the filename.

It would be something like `myfile_like_object.read()`